# Plugin mechanism in a react/typescript app

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and React. The app I'm working on needs to have a plugin mechanism - modules published on the internet can be plugged into the App. I know how to create a node/npm module. I know how to use dynamic import in Typescript. However, Typescript requires that the module be in the root path or you get the error `'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files`. Is there anyway around this? Or do I have to copy the plugin module/files into my root path? Are there any existing Typescript/node frameworks for managing this or does it have to be hand-coded?

Comment: How are you doing the dynamic import? Here is an example of a typescript project that loads plugins dynamically using `require()`: https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/blob/master/src/lib/utils/plugins.ts#L31

Comment: Any Typedoc "plugin" has to be installed via npm install. Is there no other way? Can I not take an arbitrary directory and import it? Does it have to be installed via npm?

Comment: I believe typedoc allows you to specify arbitrary JS files. How are you loading plugin. Providing you are loading the plugin dynamically with `require`, it shouldn't be a typescript restriction.